# Using QGIS layers in ArcGIS SDK for Android

Tags: qgis, arcgis-mobile

So I use QGIS for work and I am trying to create app for field work. I'm looking into ArcGIS SDK for android, but it looks like you will need to import your layer into ArcGIS server. Is there any NON-ArcGIS service I can use to import my layer onto my app, still using the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/), which is opensource. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026645/get-map-from-geoserver-to-argis-sdk-android) is an example of connecting the android ArcGIS to to a GeoServer WMS